# Using Custom Maps on Mobile Device with Datazen

Tags: maps, shapes, layer, datazen-server

I started working with Datazen two weeks ago, after two intense years of developing dashboards with Tableau.

I am loading my custom DBF + SHP file with about 250 coordinates. In the preview it nicely shows all the plots--so far so good.

However, when it is published to Datazen server, it does not show my custom map anymore (yet strangely it does in the Thumbnail of the dashboard).

My only data source is Excel, if that's relevant.

**Bottomline:** My map works, but not on server via mobile devices.
I tried with all sorts of shape-maps, never shows data on server.

**What I already checked:**

- Made sure that the maps are uploaded to the server
- Made sure that the maps were loaded in dev from the map on the server

What I get on mobile:

[image]

What I get on Datazen Desktop:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Datazen only works with .shp files that are no larger than 512KB